# MySQL Cluster with no access to Data Nodes

Tags: mysql, java, mysql-replication, mysql-cluster

I'd like to set up a MySQL Cluster for HA, but the client of the data cannot yet use ClusterJ.

I would like create 2 SQL Nodes and access *only them* from the client. i.e. No access to the NDB Data nodes.

Is this a valid configuration? Can I connect with either SQL node for reading and writing and assume that data is in sync?

Comment: The tags `mysql-replication` and `mysql-cluster` don't seem to agree. Are you using an NDB cluster or are you using MySQL servers using InnoDB or MyISAM and replication for HA?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. When you are writing/reading data through the SQL Nodes, they are actually written-to/read-from the data nodes in the cluster, to which these SQL nodes are connected to. You can use a normal `Connector/J` instead of `Cluster/J` to achieve this and it is completely valid. 
For a better understanding of how the whole cluster works check this link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-overview.html